# Oracle - literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a function which takes 2 date parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_equal
(
    date1 IN DATE,
    date2 IN DATE
)
RETURN NUMBER IS
    equal BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    equal := NVL(date1, '1999-01-01') = NVL(date2, '1999-01-01');
    IF equal THEN
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END date_equal;
/
```

Now, when I run select on the table which provides data for the function it runs okay:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(some_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM tbl
```

But when I try to use that in function call it fails:

```
SELECT date_equal(TO_DATE(some_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE(some_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) FROM tbl
```

The error message is "literal does not match format string". Does anyone know why would that happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
NVL(date1, '1999-01-01')
```

Oracle tries to convert '1999-01-01' to a date implicitly (since date1 is a date).
For doing this it uses NLS_DATE_FORMAT which may not be `yyyy-mm-dd`

You can use explicit converting:

```
NVL(date1, to_date('1999-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

or use the ANSI way

```
NVL(date1, date '1999-01-01')
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is most certainly caused by the pieace reading `NVL(date1, '1999-01-01')`.

Try `nvl(date1, date '1999-01-01')` instead.